# Give a number to return the approximated value of an Enum?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, enums, numbers

I have this enumeration:

```
Enum Lame_Bitrate
    kbps_8 = 8
    kbps_16 = 16
    kbps_24 = 24
    kbps_32 = 32
    kbps_40 = 40
    kbps_48 = 48
    kbps_56 = 56
    kbps_64 = 64
    kbps_80 = 80
    kbps_96 = 96
    kbps_112 = 112
    kbps_128 = 128
    kbps_144 = 144
    kbps_160 = 160
    kbps_192 = 192
    kbps_224 = 224
    kbps_256 = 256
    kbps_320 = 320
End Enum
```

And I would like to return the approximated value of the Enum given a number.

For example, if I have the number `190` then I expect to find the more approximated value in the Enum to return the `192` (kbps_192 value of the Enum), if I have the number `196` then again I expect to return the value `192` (not return the next value `224` because is less approximated).

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim wma_file As String = "C:\windows media audio file.wma"
    Dim wma_file_Bitrate As Integer = 172
    Dim mp3_bitrate_approximated As Integer

    mp3_bitrate_approximated = Return_Approximated_Value_Of_Enum(wma_file_Bitrate)

End Sub

private function Return_Approximated_Value_Of_Enum(byval value as integer) as integer

    return... enum.find(value).approximated...

end function
```

Exist any framework method to find the more approximated number given other number in a Enum?

I hope you can understand my question, thank you.

PS: I prefer a solution using LINQ extensions if can be.

Comment: Perhaps implement this as a binary search, then when you're between two numbers, return the one that is closest..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Indeed.  If you already have a sorted list, you can use [`List(Of T).BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find the nearest enum:

```
Dim number = 190
Dim allBitrates() As Lame_Bitrate = DirectCast([Enum].GetValues(GetType(Lame_Bitrate)), Lame_Bitrate())
Dim nearestBitrate = allBitrates.OrderBy(Function(br) Math.Abs(number - br)).First()
```

If you want to find all nearest enums (in case of multiple with the same min-distance):

```
number = 120 ' two with the same distance
Dim nearestBitrates As IEnumerable(Of Lame_Bitrate) = allBitrates.
    GroupBy(Function(br) Math.Abs(number - br)).
    OrderBy(Function(grp) grp.Key).
    First()
Console.Write(String.Join(",", nearestBitrates))
```

Output:

```
kbps_112,kbps_128
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted @Tim Schmelter solution and I've did 3 generic functions.

Just I want to share this.

· Get Nearest Enum Value:

```
' Enum Bitrate As Short : kbps_128 = 128 : kbps_192 = 192 : kbps_256 = 256 : kbps_320 = 320 : End Enum
' MsgBox(Get_Nearest_Enum_Value(Of Bitrate)(133).ToString) ' Result: kbps_128
' MsgBox(Get_Nearest_Enum_Value(Of KnownColor)(1000)) ' Result: 174
Private Function Get_Nearest_Enum_Value(Of T)(ByVal value As Long) As T

    Return [Enum].Parse(GetType(T), [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T)) _
                                          .Cast(Of Object) _
                                          .OrderBy(Function(br) Math.Abs(value - br)) _
                                          .First)

End Function
```

· Get Nearest Lower Enum Value:

```
' Enum Bitrate As Short : kbps_128 = 128 : kbps_192 = 192 : kbps_256 = 256 : kbps_320 = 320 : End Enum
' MsgBox(Get_Nearest_Lower_Enum_Value(Of Bitrate)(190).ToString) ' Result: kbps_128
' MsgBox(Get_Nearest_Lower_Enum_Value(Of Bitrate)(196).ToString) ' Result: kbps_192
Private Function Get_Nearest_Lower_Enum_Value(Of T)(ByVal value As Integer) As T

    Select Case value

        Case Is < [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T)).Cast(Of Object).First
            Return Nothing

        Case Else
            Return [Enum].Parse(GetType(T), [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T)) _
                                                  .Cast(Of Object) _
                                                  .Where(Function(enum_value) enum_value <= value) _
                                                  .Last)
    End Select

End Function
```

· Get Nearest Higher Enum Value:

```
' Enum Bitrate As Short : kbps_128 = 128 : kbps_192 = 192 : kbps_256 = 256 : kbps_320 = 320 : End Enum
' MsgBox(Get_Nearest_Higher_Enum_Value(Of Bitrate)(196).ToString) ' Result: kbps_256
' MsgBox(Get_Nearest_Higher_Enum_Value(Of KnownColor)(1000)) ' Result: 0
Private Function Get_Nearest_Higher_Enum_Value(Of T)(ByVal value As Integer) As T

    Select Case value

        Case Is > [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T)).Cast(Of Object).Last
            Return Nothing

        Case Else

            Return [Enum].Parse(GetType(T), [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T)) _
                                  .Cast(Of Object) _
                                  .Where(Function(enum_value) enum_value >= value) _
                                  .First)
    End Select

End Function
```